# Why do I need the this. qualifier to use an extension method in a master page?

Tags: .net, asp.net, extension-methods

I have the following line of code in some master page code behind, but it fails without the `this.`  Why is that?

```
Repeater rep = this.FindControlsByIdRegEx("maintTableRepeater")[0] as Repeater;
```

This is in the master page Load event, and the extension method is defined as;

```
        public static List<Control> FindControlsByIdRegEx(this Control control, string idPattern)
```

Comment: "I have the following line of code in some master page code behind": Which code??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extension methods must have an instance to "hang off of".

A method call without an object always refers to the method with that signature - in the same instance. Extension methods **are not part of the instance**. They are static methods that live elsewhere in the system, and use a little bit of compiler sugar - a trick, really - to look like they hang off of an object for ease of coding.

Comment: Yes, but everywhere else my extensions methods use the implicit 'this' in instance methods.